# How to print while loop by calling a method on an object in another class

Tags: illegalaccessexception

I'm getting this error when I run the app:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class WhileLoop tried to access field LoopClass.x (WhileLoop is in unnamed module of loader com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main$MemoryClassLoader @782663d3; LoopClass is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at WhileLoop.main(WhileLoop.java:11)

I

```
public class WhileLoop {
    LoopClass loopObj; //bring loopObj as new attribute for the WhileLoop class of type 'CodePractice'

    public WhileLoop() {    //constructor
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LoopClass loopObj = new LoopClass();
        loopObj.whileLoop(loopObj);
        System.out.println(loopObj.x);
    }

}

public class LoopClass {
int x;
    public LoopClass() {
        int x = 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    public void whileLoop(LoopClass loopObj) {   //pass loopObj as a parameter of whileLoop
        loopObj.x = 1;
        while (loopObj.x < 5) {
            loopObj.x++;
        }

    }
}
```

I want to print the contents of the while loop by calling the method on the object. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you including both of these public classes in one java file? Only one class can be marked public. Also I would change the constructor of your loop class to take in an argument so you don't have to set the x value within your whileLoop().

`public LoopClass(int x){
  this.x = x;
}`

Comment: They're in separate files. Thank you. I still don't understand why my code isn't printing though!

Comment: can you add a getter function to output the value of loopObj.x instead of trying to access it directly?
 `public int getloopx() {
  return this.x;
 }`

then within your main method call it with :  `loopObj.getloopx()`

Comment: But I want to print the while loop!

Answer (score 0):

The error can be circumvented by  declaring whileLoop to be `static`, passing `int x` as a parameter of LoopClass, assigning it the value 'this.x', and finally calling the method on the object 'loopObj'. Thank you Sachin Sunny.